# How to improve JS files loading performance (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have a problem with my web performance the problem is that I have a delay when page is loading view.

I checked development tools in Chrome, and I see that most time of load taking `angular.js`, `angular-material.js` and also `angular.material.css`.

See image below
[image]

There is how I am adding libs.

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to improve performance of load??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following things to improve performance

- You are using development version of these libraries .. use `minified versions`. Go to the folder and find `angular.min.js` and include that. Similarly, for all libraries use minified versions.
- Enable gzip compression on web server to further reduce the size.
- Enable resource caching (Add Caching headers) to cache resources locally , so, that it won't get downloaded next time.
- Add `async` & `defer` to script tags to avoid render blocking download of resources.

Comment: changed every script to minified version I'll try rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**minified files**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) that are really less voluminous for AngularJS and Angular Material:

- `angular.js` is 1.2MB, the minified is 160Ko.
  [Source](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/)
- `angular-material.js` is 1.2MB, the minified is 290Ko.
  [Source](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js)

Doing this you will improve your loading time for these files by **81%**.

<sub>Details: 100 - [450 * 100 / (1200 + 1200)] = 81.25%</sub>

Answer (score -1):

If you see their size, they are bigger than other libraries. Maybe it can be some server config to download bigger files? It can be some kind of segmentation.